# this.select() is not a function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to test some example code that I have found and one of these samples clears the selection if a grid has detail sections, so only one line is highlighted at a time.

The example is below..

```
function onRowSelect(e) {

    var selected = this.select();

    $('.k-grid tbody>.k-state-selected').not(selected).removeClass('k-state-selected')
}
```

and on the grid using

```
.Events(e => e.Change("onRowSelect()"))
```

I am using MVC and the latest builds (trials). I get the error when the page loads Uncaught TypeError: `this.select is not a function`

Can anyone point me to why this error is occurring?

Comment: This comes from the fact that `this` is probably not what you expect: in JS, it can change according to how/from where you call the function and you might get some surprises when using `this`. If you want to be sure, just print it before using it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the brackets from the change event handler definition, because currently it will be invoked during initialization:

```
.Events(e => e.Change("onRowSelect"));
```